# Can I use column name as json key in WSO2?

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

I am creating a data service in WSO2 EI. The data service outputs JSON.

The sample JSON mapping for output is as follows:

```
 "entries": {
 "entry": [
 {
 "field1": "$column1",
 "field2": "$column2"
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

My question is: can I use the column name as the json KEY? So that every key would be created dynamically. Like this:

```
 "entries": {
 "entry": [
 {
 "$column1": "$column2"
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

Currently it's producing an error and the data service becomes invalid. Any ideas how to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is the mediator that you used for JSON mapping?

Comment: Why not use JavaScript?